# numpy array plot matrix matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

```
[ [ 99  66]
  [118  67]
  [119  67]
  [120  67]
  [121  67]
  [121  68]
  [121  70]
  [ 95  71]
  [121  71]
  [123  98]
  [133 109]
  [136 110]
  [150 126]
  [153 126]
  [153 128]
  [153 129]]
```

I have this numpy array which contains sets of coordinates that I want to plot onto a matrix. How can I turn this numpy array into something like this

```
[[0 1 1 ..., 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 ..., 1 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 ..., 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 ..., 1 1 1]]`
```

So I am able to plot what I want onto my matrix

Comment: What do the 0 and 1 represent??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
width = max(coord[0] for coord in coordinates)
height = max(coord[1] for coord in coordinates)
zeros_and_ones = numpy.zeros([width, height])
for x, y in coordinates:
    zeros_and_ones[x, y] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your have a numpy array, this is likely to faster (it assumes that `coord` is positive):

```
maxcoord = np.amax(coord, axis=0)
zeros_and_ones = numpy.zeros(maxcoord)
zeros_and_ones[coord[0], coord[1]] = 1
```

If `coord` is made of integers but have negative values, you can simply rescale it